# .po translate issue for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, translate

I'm using wordpress. I have a .po file. For example, I want to translate this line. But when I do this, there is no change.

```
<h3 class="title">Personal Details</h3>
```

--.po code:

```
#: dosya/kullanici.php:16
msgid "Personal Details"
msgstr "Personel Detayları"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display translates text you must replace:

Personal Details

with the above function (see also the link of the documentation):
esc_html_e( string $text, string $domain = 'default' )

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_e/

for example you can write:

You need the function for translation and you need the text domain of your theme.

Comment: I solved the problem this way.
<?php _e ('Personal Details', 'siteyonetim'); ?> What is the diffrence "esc_html_e" and "_e".

Comment: When you are dealing with code or mark up languages as HTML for safe reasons you must escape characters. When using _e you just translate eith esc_html_e you escape markup and translate (more secure). 
See Docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_e/

Also, if you want, read the above article for bette understanding on escaping https://www.inanimatt.com/php-output-escaping.html

Answer (score 0):

Define WPLANG inside of wp-config.php to your chosen language. For example, if you wanted to use french, then you need to define define ('WPLANG', 'fr_FR'); in wp-config.php file. Also put .po file in current theme folder.